# ¿Cómo obtener el contexto de un constructor?

Tags: javascript

```js
function A() {
  

  var node = new B();
  
  
}

function B() {
  
  this.age = 15;
  
}

th.bind(A)();

function th(){
  
  console.log(this.age * 2);
  
}
```

En este caso ***necesito ejecutar una función llamada*** `th()`, la cual con el método `bind()` se supone que obtengo el contexto de `B()`, pero ¿cómo puedo obtenerlo ***sin modificar*** `var node`?

Comment: Amigo creo que te perdiste entre tanto constructor, te recomiendo el siguiente articulo: [Javascript Constructors and Prototypes](http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/)

Answer (score 2):

En tu función `A` te estas olvidando de devolver `node`

```
function A() {
    var node = new B();
    return node;
}
```

Si esto fuera así luego puedes bindear no a `A` sino al resultado de llamar a A: `A()` (que por cierto devuelve un `B`) a la función `th()` y finalmente llamar a la función devuelta por el `bind` mediante un par de paréntesis más de esta manera.

```js
function A() {
    var node = new B();
    return node;
}

function B() {
    this.age = 15;
}

function th() {
    console.log(this.age * 2);
}

th.bind(A())();
```

Te recomiendo que leas la documentación de `bind` aquí: [Function.prototype.bind() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind)